# Sending push notification from firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I want to send notification from firebase cloud messaging. For that I went to compose notification section under cloud messaging, provided all the informations required for. When I tested it by adding FCM-token, Its working fine.

But, while scheduling it, I want to target only one specific user.So Under target section I am setting device and for the value I am putting FCM-token.
[image]

[image]

But no push notification is coming.Is there anything I am doing wrong or value of device should be other than FCM-token

Comment: post what you have done so far.

Comment: Add FirebaseMessagingService onreceived code

Comment: Everything is working fine while I am testing or push notification coming from server.But while pusblishing the notification not woking.I just need to know, what should be the value for device mentioned in the above picture.Is it FCM-token or another value?? @GaneshPokale

Comment: You need to put the value that you have saved as 'Device' for that user in the FCM console.